# Updating data in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to code a website where users have profile pages. I want them to be able to edit their profile information that they have already entered. But there is an about me section where users are expected to include a large amount of detail about themselves. 
I have used the SQL UPDATE statement which works fine to override the data which is already there but I'm wondering if there is a way to extract the data that is there and allow the user to edit this and then post the updated version back to the table?
Any help on an approach to this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to make a SELECT to display user infos on their user page and incorporate the values into a form, and then you will handle the form to update the datas (either in the same php file or another one)

I suggest you to visit this tutorial : [Create user editing area](http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-14-members-area-system-in-php-mysql-members-users-system-area-log-sign.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
The below code fetch the user info from the database and display it in a form.


 <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table where username = '$username'";
           $query = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);
           $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
          echo "<form action='update_user_info.php' method='post'>
          <input type='text' name='full_name' value='$fetch['full_name']' >
          <input type='text' name='address' value='$fetch['address']' >
          <textarea title='about' name='about'>$fetch['about_user']</textarea>
          <input type='submit' name='btn_update' value='Save'>
</form>?>
```

Here is what the update_user_info will look like.

```
    <?php $sql = "UPDATE user_table SET full_name = '$_POST['full_name']' WHERE username = '$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);
//I hope you can find your way from here ?>
```